# Error handling in R in RStudio -- don't invoke debugger?

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I'm trying to create error messages similar to those you can find in R package `dplyr` that don't invoke RStudio's debugger and simply stop and print an informative message.

So for example in RStudio if you use:

`library(dplyr)
group_by(blah)`

You get an informative error but the debugger is not invoked so the "interruption" to the user is minimal, they realize the issue and fix the code. But when I use

```
myfunc<-function(val){
  if(val>3) stop("This is error", call.=FALSE)
}

myfunc(4)
```

The debugger is triggered and it's more unpleasant. How do I simply give a nice error message with out starting the debugger? What is the difference in how `dplyr` is creating error messages and mine? I did look at the GitHub repo but wasn't sure.

Comment: Your above code does not trigger my debugger, it just prints `Error: This is error` in the console. In your IDE, maybe you can change your settings under `Debug -> On Error`; or in `Tools -> Global options... -> [Use debug error handler only when my code contains errors]` (I have this option checked).

Comment: Do you want to use `warning()`, rather than `stop()`?

Comment: Thanks! Similar to the dplyr code, though, I don't want the debugger invoked even if the user has the "break in code" option selected because not all users will know to uncheck this.

Comment: No to warning() because this will simply print a warning and keep going -- I need the code to stop.

Comment: As far as I can tell the dplyr error messages are just regular error messages except call. is always set to false. That shouldn't effect the debugger behaviour but you could try it.

Comment: Yes, I could not see the difference. Note that in my code above call. is set to FALSE.